# C# Sendkeys how to send tilde without sending enter

Tags: c#, sendkeys

In my code, I am trying to send a tilde (~) to the users program. Everytime I send ~ it presses enter and the code does not get to continue sending the rest of the keys.

I have tried:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("([~])");
SendKeys.SendWait("~");
SendKeys.SendWait("{[~]}");
```

they all just press the enter button and don't send the actual tilde

Comment: Doesn't the documentation say to enclose special characters like this? `{~}`

Comment: Complete your SO user profile, at least mention what country you're from.  So we'll have an idea what your keyboard layout looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use "{+}". To specify brace characters, use "{{}" and "{}}". Brackets ([ ]) have no special meaning to SendKeys, but you must enclose them in braces.

So this should work:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{~}");
```

The documentation also remarks:

> If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you, the documentation is kind of hard for me to understand, but since you helped explain it, it make much more sense.

Comment: +1 for answering question, but OP explained it by copying the documentation (verbatim) that's "hard to understand"...

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the correct way is to enclose it in curly braces as @user1071777 said.

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to
>   specify the plus sign, use "{+}".

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx